# Создание папки в директории приложения

Tags: android, java

Есть код, сохраняющий данные в файл в директории приложения.

```
try {
    OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("nameOfFile.txt", 0);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    osw.write("data");
    osw.close();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

А нужно, чтобы программа проверяла наличие папки Folder в директории приложения, при её отсутствии создавала папку, а затем сохраняла файл в папку Folder в директории приложения.
Находил мануалы по созданию папки по определенному пути (на карту памяти), но мне непонятно, какой путь указывать для хранилища приложения.

Comment: Проверка на существование файла и создание папки при отсутствии
Context c = getApplicationContext();
        File file = new File(c.getFilesDir(), "/Folder");
        if (file.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "exists");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "not exists");
            file.mkdir();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так а вопрос где? В чём проблема-то? 
[На вот тебе ссылка про то как создавать папки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html). Прежде чем задавать вопросы, неплохо бы поучить Яву.

[на ещё](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_file_class.htm), и [ещё](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) почитай про методы. [А вот](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)  тут как создаются папки в андроиде. Учи мат часть.

Answer (score 4):

> но мне непонятно, какой путь указывать для хранилища приложения.

Все просто. Ссылку на каталог в директории приложения можно получить вызовом метода

```
Context.getFilesDir()
```

Далее уже по пути, проложенному нервным [[@argamidon](/users/14145/argamidon)](/users/14145/argamidon). :)